# Traffic forecasting on Google DFP

Tags: forecasting, google-dfp, traffic

Do you need a Google DFP Premium account to use the traffic forecasting feature? If not then why does it load continuously and say "beta"? How much is Google DFP Premium? Do you really need 90 million impressions per month to use it or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

#### Do you need a Google DFP Premium account to use the traffic forecasting feature?

No you don't

#### If not then why does it load continuously and say "beta"

Because this is a fairly complex and error-prone piece of software. I think claiming it `beta` leaves a room for an excuse "hey this product is still in beta" if something is goes wrong. And there's lots of things that may go wrong with this tool.

#### How much is Google DFP Premium

You're to contact your account managers to get the exact price.
Check out this [article](http://adtagmacros.com/difference-dfp-small-business-dfp-premium/) to see the approximate numbers (note this is an unofficial source, everything may have changed!)

> 0 - 90 Millions 0$ CPM
>
> 90 Millions – 200 Millions    0.0167$ CPM
>
> 200 Millions – 500 Millions   0.014$ CPM
>
> ... and so on depending on your traffic volume

#### Do you really need 90 million impressions per month to use it or is there another way?

Not sure about exactly 90 millions, but you definitely need to have a high-volume project